# Get the 3rd part of the string in Postgres

Tags: string, postgresql, substring

I have data like,

```
ab-volt-ssn-dev
ab-volt-lnid-dev
ab-volt-ssn-hamp-dev
ab-volt-cf-apnt-test
```

I need output to be like,

```
ssn
lnid
ssn
cf
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use split_part()

```
select split_part('ab-volt-ssn-hamp-dev', '-', 3);
```

If you need to access multiple parts, then converting it to an array might be easier:

```
select elements[1],
       elements[2],
       elements[3],
       elements[4]
from (
   select string_to_array(the_column, '-') as elements
   from the_table
) t;
```